# prawn_pdf - able to display data, how to format the same in to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

able generate pdf with prawn_pdf with specific bill_ids.

pdf.rb

```
def initialize(dbills)
@dbills = dbills

@dbills.each do |bill|
    text "#{bill.client.idno} #{bill.billno} #{bill.client.name} 
    #{bill.bill_rep_total_amount} #{bill.discount} #{ bill.record_total_amount}"

end
```

and able to display the content like

id0001 01 Client1 1000 100 900

id0002 02 Client5 8000 100 7900

id0005 03 Client8 600 0 600

id0007 04 Client3 300 50 250

id0009 05 Client2 9000 2000 7000

but how to format the same in to descent table using prawn_pdf in rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

was able to format the same using **map** which is different than map in rails so was confused

```
@dbills.map do |bill|
 bill.billdt, bill.billno, bill.patient.regno, bill.patient.name, bill.bill_rep_total_amount, bill.discount, bill.bill_rep_total_amount - bill.discount ]
end
```